# Strange black bar at the bottom of the screen android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K5-7GF4vTdt9-gQbTmqVJgSnNlUZJHSh/view?usp=sharing)

app theme: Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar
this id
this is the manifest:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.BaseActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_base"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

main activity layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/main_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    />
   <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_text_color"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/ nav_active_item_TextAppearance"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/nav_inactive_item_TextAppearance"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_text_color"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

All activities have a black bar at the bottom of the screen like the screenshot